# Executar função JavaScript no evento click de um botão dentro de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Bom dia, tenho uma tabela e em cada linha dessa tabela tenho um botão, quando eu clicar nesse botão preciso que seja executada uma função mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso por que acho que não estou sabendo usar os seletores corretos.

Tabela:

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-striped">
    <tr id="cabecalho">
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Insumo
        </th>
        <th>
            TD
        </th>
        <th>
            Unidade
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade
        </th>
        <th>
            Adicionar
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script que gera o corpo da tabela:

```
$('#pesquisar').click(function () {
    $('.corpoTbl').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/RCM/ListarMateriais",
        type: "POST",
        data: { nome: $('#NomeMaterial').val() },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (I, item) {
                $('#tbl').append("<tr class=\"corpoTbl\"> <td class=\"id\">" + item.ID + "</td><td>" + item.Nome + "</td><td>" + item.TD + "</td><td>" + item.Unidade +
                    "</td><td> <input class=\"qtda\" type=\"text\" value=\"0\" style=\"width: 50px;\" /> </td><td> <input class=\"btn\" type=\"button\" value=\"Adicionar\" /> </td></tr>")
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Script que quero que seja executado no click do botão.

```
$('#tbl .btn').click(function () {
    var Qtd = $('.qtda');
    var Id = $('.id');    
    if (Qtd.value != "0" && Qtd.value != "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/RCM/AddMaterial",
            type: "POST",
            data: { "Qtd": $('.qtda').Value, "Id": Id.textContent }
        })
        alert("Materiais Adicionados!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Informe a quantidade do material!")
    }

})
```

Comment: Mas, cadê o html pra `#pesquisar`, `.corpoTbl`, `#tbl .btn`..? Por favor, confira o guia [**Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @brasofilo esses elementos são criados dinamicamente, com JavaScript. Está no script da pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema me parece que você está tentando encontrar os botões para esperar os clicks antes de os botões existirem na página, já que eles são adicionados mais tardes, via ajax.

A solução mais simples seria usar eventos delegados, onde você esperará por clicks na tabela, pois ela já está na página desde o início, filtrando para apenas os clicks que vêm dos botões:

```
$('#tbl').on('click', '.btn', function (event) {
    var $botao = $(event.target);
    var $tr = $botao.closest('tr');
    var $qtda = $tr.find('.qtda');
    var $id = $tr.find('.id');    
    if ($qtda.val() !== "0" && $qtda.val() !== "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/RCM/AddMaterial",
            type: "POST",
            data: { "Qtd": $qtda.val(), "Id": $id.text() }
        })
        alert("Materiais Adicionados!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Informe a quantidade do material!")
    }

})
```

Comment: Deu certo, realmente acho que era isso que você falou, eu nunca ia ter pensado nisso, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Parece estar tudo certo. Fez alguns testes de debug? Se não fez, experimente:

```
console.log("nbtn = " + $('#tbl .btn').length);

$('#tbl .btn').click(function () {

    alert("ok");

    var Qtd = $('.qtda');
    var Id = $('.id');    
    if (Qtd.value != "0" && Qtd.value != "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/RCM/AddMaterial",
            type: "POST",
            data: { "Qtd": $('.qtda').Value, "Id": Id.textContent }
        })
        alert("Materiais Adicionados!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Informe a quantidade do material!")
    }

})
```

Teste no Firefox com o firebug, que é mais fácil para ler o resultado do console.log.