# Função JS não executa - $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom dia a todos ,

Comecei a estudar javascript recentemente e estou com um problema que nao consegui resolver.

Segue a baixo:

Tenho uma pagina que estou fazendo como se fosse um Quiz.

Segue o Código completo da pagina:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {

    function loop_html(id_1, id_2, resposta_1, resposta_2, link_1, link_2, qtd) {
      var id = []; //crio o array 'id'
      id[1] = id_1; //atribuo o valor de ao primeiro array
      id[2] = id_2; //atribuo o valor de ao segundo array

      var resposta = []; //crio o array 'resposta'
      resposta[1] = resposta_1; //atribuo o valor de ao primeiro array
      resposta[2] = resposta_2; //atribuo o valor de ao segundo array

      var link = []; //crio o array 'link'
      link[1] = link_1; //atribuo o valor de ao primeiro array
      link[2] = link_2; //atribuo o valor de ao segundo array

      var pt_1 = []; //crio o array
      var pt_2 = []; //crio o array
      var pt_3 = []; //crio o array
      var pt_4 = []; //crio o array
      var pt_5 = []; //crio o array
      var pt_6 = []; //crio o array
      var html = []; //crio o array

      for (i = 1; i <= qtd; i++) { //aqui , eu crio os botoes que terao as opções de escolha do usuario

        pt_1[i] = '<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" id="id_botao_' + i + '">';
        pt_2[i] = '<div class="dashboard-stat red-thunderbird" id="local_resposta">';
        pt_3[i] = '<a href="' + link[i] + '" id="link_' + i + '">';
        pt_4[i] = '<button type="button" class="botao color' + i + '" id="btn_resposta_' + i + '" value="' + id[i] + '">';
        pt_5[i] = '<span id="texto_botao">' + resposta[i] + '</span>';
        pt_6[i] = '</button> </a> </div> </div>';

        html[i] = pt_1[i] + pt_2[i] + pt_3[i] + pt_4[i] + pt_5[i] + pt_6[i];

        document.getElementById("div_botoes_" + i).innerHTML = html[i];
      }

    }

    function frase_script_primeira_execucao() {

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/admin2/controllers/pegar_frase_script.php?id_frase=1", //URL de destino
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        success: function(json) {

          var id_1 = (json.id_1); //joga o retorno json na variavel id_1
          var id_2 = (json.id_2); //joga o retorno json na variavel id_2
          var link_1 = (json.link_1); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel link_1
          var link_2 = (json.link_2); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel link_2
          var resposta_1 = (json.resposta_1); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel resposta_1
          var resposta_2 = (json.resposta_2); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel resposta_2
          var qtd = (json.qtd_botao); ////pega o retorno e joga na variavel qtd_1

          $('#pergunta').html(json.frase); //cria o HTML com o json "frase" 

          loop_html(id_1, id_2, resposta_1, resposta_2, link_1, link_2, qtd); //passa os valores para a funcao "loop_html"
        }
      });
    }

    function frase_script(id) { //mando requisiçao para pagina , para pegar os dados e serem exibidos
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/admin2/controllers/pegar_frase_script.php?id_frase=" + id, //URL de destino
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        success: function(json) {

          var id_1 = (json.id_1); //joga o retorno json na variavel id_1
          var id_2 = (json.id_2); //joga o retorno json na variavel id_2
          var link_1 = (json.link_1); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel link_1
          var link_2 = (json.link_2); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel link_2
          var resposta_1 = (json.resposta_1); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel resposta_1
          var resposta_2 = (json.resposta_2); //pega o retorno e joga na variavel resposta_2
          var qtd = (json.qtd_botao); ////pega o retorno e joga na variavel qtd_1

          $('#pergunta').html(json.frase); //cria o HTML com o json "frase" 

          loop_html(id_1, id_2, resposta_1, resposta_2, link_1, link_2, qtd); //passa os valores para a funcao "loop_html"
        }
      });
    }

    $("#btn_resposta_1").click( //ao clicar no botao 01 , executa a funcao
      function() {
        var id = $("#btn_resposta_1").val(); //pega o valor do botao
        frase_script(id); //chama a funcao que pega a frase , informando o ID da proxima frase
      }
    );

    $("#btn_resposta_2").click( //ao clicar no botao 02 , executa a funcao
      function() {
        var id = $("#btn_resposta_2").val(); //pega o valor do botao
        frase_script(id); //chama a funcao que pega a frase , informando o ID da proxima frase
      }
    );

    frase_script_primeira_execucao(); //chama a funcao que pega a 1 frase na execuçao do script


    var efeitos = ['slideToggle', 'slideDown', 'fadeToggle', 'fadeIn']; //array com tipos de efeito toogle

    function embaralhar_efeito(o) { //funcao que embaralha e retorna um efeito
      for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
      return o[0]; //O [0] faz retornar somente o 1 array
    }

    function efeito_pergunta(efeitos) { // o (efeitos) é a variavel que recebe o valor do array com os efeitos jquery

      var efeito_toogle = embaralhar_efeito(efeitos); //aciona a funcao que embaralha os efeitos
      $("#div_pergunta")[efeito_toogle](500); //atribui o efeito toogle a div "div_pergunta"
    }

    function efeito_botao_1(efeitos) { // o (efeitos) é a variavel que recebe o valor do array com os efeitos jquery

      var efeito_toogle = embaralhar_efeito(efeitos); //aciona a funcao que embaralha os efeitos
      $("#id_botao_1")[efeito_toogle](500); //atribui o efeito toogle a div "id_botao_1"
    }

    function efeito_botao_2(efeitos) { // o (efeitos) é a variavel que recebe o valor do array com os efeitos jquery

      var efeito_toogle = embaralhar_efeito(efeitos); //aciona a funcao que embaralha os efeitos
      $("#id_botao_2")[efeito_toogle](500); //atribui o efeito toogle a div "id_botao_1"
    }

    function efeito_set_time_out(){ //funcao que chama a funcoes acima , ordenadamente
 setTimeout(
  function(){ 
   
   efeito_pergunta(efeitos); // "efeitos" é a variavel que contem os array 
   
   setTimeout(
    function(){
     
     efeito_botao_1(efeitos); // "efeitos" é a variavel que contem os array 
     
     setTimeout(
      function(){ 
      
       efeito_botao_2(efeitos); // "efeitos" é a variavel que contem os array
       
       setTimeout(
        function(){ 
      
        efeito_botao_3(efeitos); // "efeitos" é a variavel que contem os array 
        
        setTimeout(
         function(){ 
      
         efeito_botao_4(efeitos); // "efeitos" é a variavel que contem os array 
        }, 500);//efeito botao_4
       }, 500);//efeito botao_3
      }, 500);//efeito_botao_2
    }, 500);//efeito_botao_1
   },500);//efeito pergunta
   
 }//main function efeito_set_time_out

    efeito_set_time_out(); //chama a funcao de controle de tempo

    $("#btn_resposta_1").click( //ao clicar no botao 01 , executa a funcao
      function() {

        $("#div_pergunta").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div de pergunta
        $("#id_botao_1").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 01
        $("#id_botao_2").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 02
        efeito_set_time_out();
      }
    );

    $("#btn_resposta_2").click( //ao clicar no botao 02 , executa a funcao
      function() {

        $("#div_pergunta").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div de pergunta
        $("#id_botao_1").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 01
        $("#id_botao_2").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 02
        efeito_set_time_out();
      }
    );

  });
```

```css
.botao {
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border: 1px solid #ffcc00;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff, 0 2px 3px #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.color1 {
  background-color: red !important;
}
.color2 {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.color3 {
  background-color: green !important;
}
.color1:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px #fff, 0 2px 3px #666;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(red), to(#ff6600)) !important;
}
.color2:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px #fff, 0 2px 3px #666;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(blue), to(#ff6600)) !important;
}
.color3:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px #fff, 0 2px 3px #666;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(green), to(#ff6600)) !important;
}
.botao:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px #fff, 0 1px 3px #666 !important;
  top: 2px
}
.botao a,
.botao a:active,
.botao a:hover,
.botao a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666;
}
#local_resposta {
  border-radius: 40px!important;
}
.number {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#div_pergunta,
#id_botao_1,
#id_botao_2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="portlet box red">
  <div class="portlet-title">
    <div class="caption">
      <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Perguntas
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet-body">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="dashboard-stat orange" style="border-radius:20px!important;" id="div_pergunta">
            <div class="visual">

            </div>
            <div class="detail">
              <div class="number">
                <span id="pergunta"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

        <span id="div_botoes_1"></span>
        <span id="div_botoes_2"></span>
        <span id="div_botoes_3"></span> 

      </div>
      <!-- :: COL MD 12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- ::ROW :: -->
  </div>
</div>
```

O meu problema ,começou quando criei a função "loop_html", que cria os botões automaticamente.Quando comecei a faze-la ,eu criei os botões manualmente,mas tem perguntas que podem ter 2 respostas e perguntas que podem ter 4 resposta, ou seja , é dinâmico , assim eu não posso criar os botões manualmente pois não sei quantos serão necessários.

Quando co clico nos botoes  , era para chamar algumas funções , mas não sei por que essas funções não são acionadas. A primeira função "frase_script_primeira_execucao" funciona , ela manda a requisição para a pagina ,pega o valor , chama a função "loop_html" que traz os botões. Depois disso , nao funciona mais nada.

Como posso fazer para as funções voltarem a funcionar ?

Ps.: Aqui da para ver a funcao que cria os botoes em ação http://jsfiddle.net/h_felix/dut2fk69/

Desde já , grato.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30556/discussion-on-question-by-henrique-felix-funcao-js-nao-executa-is-not-define)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde  ,

Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer ao @EmirMarques por ter dedicado um tempo a me ajudar.

Estava navegando pelo stack , quando encontrei o seguinte post.

[Executar função JavaScript no evento click de um botão dentro de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30677/executar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-javascript-no-evento-click-de-um-bot%C3%A3o-dentro-de-uma-tabela).

Nele, o autor diz:

> O problema me parece que você está tentando encontrar os botões para esperar os clicks antes de os botões existirem na página, já que eles são adicionados mais tardes, via ajax.

Acreditei que este poderia ser o meu problema , pois a situaçao é bem semelhante.

Então , não sei se é a maneira correta , mas criei a funcao :

```
function carrega_funco_botao(){

setTimeout(
    function(){ 
        $("#btn_resposta_1").click( //ao clicar no botao 01 , executa a funcao
            function(){
                var id = $("#btn_resposta_1").val();  //pega o valor do botao
                frase_script(id); //chama a funcao que pega a frase , informando o ID da proxima frase
            }
        );

        $("#btn_resposta_2").click(  //ao clicar no botao 02 , executa a funcao
            function(){
                var id = $("#btn_resposta_2").val();  //pega o valor do botao
                frase_script(id); //chama a funcao que pega a frase , informando o ID da proxima frase
            }
        );
    },2000);

setTimeout(
    function(){

        $("#btn_resposta_1").click( //ao clicar no botao 02 , executa a funcao
            function(){

                $("#div_pergunta").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div de pergunta
                $("#id_botao_1").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 01
                $("#id_botao_2").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 02
                efeito_set_time_out();
            }
        );

        $("#btn_resposta_2").click( //ao clicar no botao 02 , executa a funcao
            function(){

                $("#div_pergunta").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div de pergunta
                $("#id_botao_1").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 01
                $("#id_botao_2").slideUp(500); //efeito toogle que sobe a div do botao 02
                efeito_set_time_out();
            }
        );
    },2000);
}
```

E chamo ela toda vez que gero o html dos botoes.

Segue o codigo completo de como ficou.

http://jsfiddle.net/h_felix/Ls19mdx7/3/

grato